# Sequelize Model.associations[alias]. There is another way to get associated models?

Tags: sequelize.js

I was trying to figure out if with a model class(not an instance), I can get all related associations(belongsTo, hasOne, hasMany, etc.) with respective classes. I found Model.associations property which isn't documented, so if possible, i'd like to avoid use it. Do you guys know how about get this result?

My goal, it's just pass a string as model in query and still set other properties like where conditions.

This way, works fine.

```
Model.findAll({
    include:['partner']
})
```

But if want to do something like this:

```
Model.findAll({
    include:[
         {
            model: 'partner',
            where: {id:2}
         }
    ]
})
```

I need to import the model, and that's fine, it works too. I just want to pass an string and parse in a higher class, because it's annoying keep importing models, and it makes impossible dynamic include without so much conditions.

Comment: What are you passing here ` model: ......,` also can you show your association setup?

Comment: Hi @SujeetAgrahari, to make this work, I need to pass class Model, but, I want to pass a string in model property, as like as when I have just an array: {include: ['model1','model2','model3']}. I just edited the post. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include model, without importing it. You can do that with defining an alias on your association.

```
User.hasMany(models.Tool, { as: 'Instruments'}); // here Intruments is alias to Tool
```

You can also include by alias name by specifying a string that matches the association alias:

```
User.findAll({ include: 'Instruments' }); // Also works
User.findAll({ include: { association: 'Instruments' } }); // Also works
```

Output:

```
[{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "id": 1,
  "Instruments": [{
    "name": "Scissor",
    "id": 1,
    "userId": 1
  }]
}]
```

For more information [read here.](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html#fetching-an-aliased-association)